# JSON text did not start with array Error with AFNetworking

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, afnetworking

I am using the below code to use perform a GET request. In reverse manner am sending the params into server and data storing in the server fine. But am getting the error 
*** JSON text did not start with array ***

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
        NSDictionary *params = @{@"emails": emailid,
                                 @"password": paswrd,
                                 @"gender": gende,
                                 @"firstname":name1,
                                 @"lastname":firstname1,
                                 @"dateofBirth":dob1,
                                 @"Country":count
                                 };

        [manager GET:@"http://37.187.152.236:91/EmployeeSvc.svc/AddEmployee?"
          parameters:params
             success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
                 NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
             } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
                 NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
             }];
```

[image: This response am getting]

Comment: Are you sure sending the `GET` request with such params? Response must be a valid JSON, seems like some troubles on the server side.

Comment: Uh, could you please post the JSON?  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check your serve Content-Type,If is text/html,you need code this:

```
 manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet setWithObject:@"text/html"];
```

Answer (score 2):

```
-(void) testHTTPS {
    AFSecurityPolicy *securityPolicy = [[AFSecurityPolicy alloc] init];
    [securityPolicy setAllowInvalidCertificates:YES];

    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
    [manager setSecurityPolicy:securityPolicy];
    manager.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];

    [manager GET:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", HOST] parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseObject encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSLog(@"%@", string);
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    }];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This problem can be due to bad JSON string. By Bad JSON string, I mean that your JSON response might not be starting with the expected characters i.e **'['** or **'{'**. The starting characters must always be anyone of the above two.

Also there might be a chance that your JSON response is embedded in some kind of XML string. This happened to me and for me, it was just bad JSON response like I explained and I solved it by proper parsing.

Check this image. This is what bad JSON can look like.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<string xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
[{"Title":"DemoTitle","CreationDate":"06/06/2014","Description":"DemoDescription"}]
</string>
```

As you can see, JSON is embedded in XML string.**strong text**Also, check your JSON response on this site : http://jsonlint.com/

This will show you if the JSON you receive is valid for parsing or not.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

This is the server side error when your server is not responding the JSON response OR Response is  **not a valid JSON** because this error is appears when AF networking library unable to parse the JSON response.
Please check it with your server side about the response

Comment: data is storing properly in server .. but mean while am getting this error

Comment: Its not storing data issue. this issue when they are return the data in API response.